# /}/ doesn't match sometimes }

Tags: php, regex

regex pattern /}/ sometimes matches } and sometimes doesn't.

Is there any know bug in PHP?
I am using PHP 5.40

I am assuming that } doesn't need to be escaped for match.
Although `/\}/` always matches } but this behavior seems to be wrong.

This [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) also says 11 metacharacters that need to be escaped only.

there are 11 characters with special meanings: the opening square bracket [, the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus sign +, the opening round bracket ( and the closing round bracket ). These special characters are often called "metacharacters".

for an example `-` is a metacharacter as per [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) but that doesn't need to be escaped and `/-/` works fine in PHP, why not `}`?

```
$subject = 'find me}';
$pattern = '/}/';
$isMatch = preg_match($pattern,$subject,$matches);

echo 'Match Found = ' . $isMatch . '<br />';
print_r($matches);
```

sometimes i get following

```
Match Found = 0
Array ( )
```

sometimes i get following

```
Match Found = 1
Array ( [0] => } )
```

Comment: Isn't `}` a reserved character in a regular expression?

Comment: @matt depends on the regex engine

Comment: @matt - and ] is also reserved character for regex but /-/ or /]/ works fine in PHP

Comment: What is different between the times when it works, and the times when it doesn't?

Comment: Try using [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) just in case.

Comment: it's 3:1 ratio, 3 is for match and 1 for no match

Comment: @matt for workaround /\}/ is good enough but just interested in PHP implementation

Comment: @Praveen but what differs other than the result? The input, the time of day, the presence or lack of a kitten on your keyboard?

Comment: `preg_quote()` isn't a workaround. That's the implementation.

Comment: Guessing, if there's no opening brace, maybe you don't need to escape the closing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php according to that { and } are regular expression characters

Comment: but everyone doesn't need to be escaped right?

Comment: If you are selecting a }, to not escape it is asking for trouble for no potential gain.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why `/}/` works sometimes but not others - I know in Java it (`"}"`) will never work unless it's escaped, in .Net I've never *had* to escape it, but it will understand if I do - It all depends on the internal workings of the regex engine, but I'm pretty sure escaping it will work in almost all flavors or regex - the only one that will break that I know of is POSIX BRE, if you're *stuck* using that :-P, but that is because all metacharacters must be escaped IIRC

Answer (score 1):

Certain characters must be escaped, } is one of the, - on the other hand is not  Here is a list of the ones that must be escaped http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php:

```
. \ + * ? ^ $ [ ] ( ) { } < > = ! | :
```

As you can see `-` is not part of this list, so it doesn't need to be escaped.

So the correct code would be:

```
$subject = 'find me}';
$pattern = '/\}/';
$isMatch = preg_match($pattern,$subject,$matches);

echo 'Match Found = ' . $isMatch . '<br />';
print_r($matches);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: can you please put the source or doc link?

Answer (score 0):

In PCRE, `}` needs to be escaped, it's used to denote a number of matches:

```
/x{4}/
```

It can also be used to denote a range:

```
/x{1,4}/
```

Comment: This is not necessarily incorrect. Why the -1? Help the rest of us out, anonymous down-voter!

Comment: -1 for the overgeneralised, or imprecise depending on your viewpoint, statement that "`}` needs to be escaped".  To clarify, `}` has meaning ("metacharacter") as part of a brace pair (to denote a quantifier or several other uncommon uses) or delimiter pair; it only **needs** to be escaped when it would otherwise wrongly be interpreted as one of those.

Comment: So you would rather a character be matched with intermittent unexpected behavior. It clearly NEEDS to be escaped, whether it works anyway or not.

Comment: Learn to use the tool you're working with. It's the same reason why we don't go around escaping every single character in a PHP double-quoted string.